# Marlin file manager doesn't launch due to libunity.so.6 missing

Tags: unity, gnome, libraries, marlin

I just installed Marlin file browser, from the marlin-dev ppa.

Problem is, wehn i try to launch it, i get this error:

```
stewart@StudioLaptop2:~$ marlin
marlin: error while loading shared libraries: libunity.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What should I do?

P.S. - I've tried it in Gnome-shell and Unity, but get same error :(

Comment: Remove Unity 5.0 and install back the original Ubuntu 11.10 Unity and it will work. Without it, many applications compiled against Unity will fail to start.

Answer (score 1):

Not a very proper solution ...

```
  sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libunity.so.9 /usr/lib/libunity.so.6
```

... but it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Solution (at least for ubuntu 11.10 oneiric ocelot):

```
sudo apt-get install libunity6
```

To find the package of an installed file:

```
$ dpkg -S libunity6
libunity6: /usr/lib/libunity.so.6
```

To find the package of a missing file:

1. Go to http://packages.ubuntu.com
2. Scroll down to "Search the contents of packages" and type in the filename, e.g. libunity.so.6

..and voila!

Answer (score -1):

Install apt-find and search the required packages:

apt-find libunity.so.6

It should give You the name of the package containing the required lib. Then write:

sudo apt-get install package_name

It will help only if the problem occurs because of unresolved dependencies. If it doesn't help, try reinstalling the software.

Comment: what You mean? Where is written that there's no apt-find?

Comment: My apologies, it appears the answer I linked to has been deleted. Regardless, I'm just pointing out that I too cannot locate `apt-find` in the official repositories. What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Also, searching for `apt-find` at [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) turns up nothing, regardless of version. I'm guessing you are using an older release (i.e., pre-Lucid).

Comment: Im using Lucid, but haven't been using apt-find for a while so i just didn't know it has been removed. What is instead of it?

Comment: It looks like the command to use is now `apt-file` (specifically, the `apt-find libunity.so.6` command would be replaced by `apt-file search libunity.so.6`).